# TableView height in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

My tableview add blank space to the end of the cells.

I don't know why, how do I fix this problem? (For ex I have 50 cells, two of them you can see here because this is last two cells)

[image]

Comment: show your tableview delegate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know without seeing your code, but because your cells have varied heights, you should probably start by implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

If you end up wanting more manual control over the table's height, take a look at its `contentSize` property.